# How to change the background color of curses applications?

Tags: terminal, colors, ncurses

I hate that blue background which is everywhere in ncurses applications like: irssi, mc, tig, … I want to change that color, how can I do it?

I know that midnight commander has themes, but what about global settings for all CLI programs? I found that there's `setterm` in Linux and `vidcontrol` in FreeBSD, but `vidcontrol` doesn't work for me, and I think it's not that what I need because it's for VESA stuff. I'm working over ssh here.

Comment: What SSH client?

Comment: Nothing ssh client (lol what did you asked?)

Comment: The color used is usually built into the application and has nothing to do with the shell.

Comment: @holms you said you're working over ssh.  I know putty lets you redefine the colors.  If you're working in an OSX terminal, there's probably some way to do it (since that's what the OSX terminal themes do).

Comment: ok I just overrided color in iterm2 application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some terminals like xterm allow to redefine the colors via resource files or dynamically, and if it's exposed correctly in the terminfo entry for $TERM, you can do it with:

```
tput initc 4 1000 0 0
```

Change ANSI color 4 (normally blue) to RGB (1000, 0 0), that is bright red.

If the terminal doesn't support redefining colours (see `infocmp -1 | grep initc`), you can also, for applications that use terminfo, trick them into sending different escape sequences to request colour 4 (blue).

```
infocmp -x > terminal.info
```

Edit `terminal.info`, replace the name of the terminal with something like "myterm", and edit the "setab" property (set ANSI background).

Instead of

```
setab=\E[4%p1%dm
```

That is:

```
tput setab 4
```

sends ^[[44m, change it to:

```
setab=\E[4%?%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%d%;m
```

The `%? ....`, is an if-then-else, to say send "1" when asked for "4" and the requested one otherwise.

So

```
tput setab 4
```

will send `^[[41m`, (red) and `tput setab 5` will send `^[[45m`

Then, compile it with:

```
TERMINFO=$HOME/.terminfo tic -x terminal.info
```

and use it as:

```
TERMINFO=$HOME/.terminfo TERM=myterm the-application-to-trick
```

That only works if the application uses the terminfo database to send sequences to the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

if you switch your TERM variable to a terminal that does not support ANSI colors, you will not see any blue background anymore.